# Moving table to new database in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Heres what I want to do: 
I am working with one database, for simplicity I will name it "d1". and I only need to query two tables from this database. I need to isolate only last years data from this database though(that is the only info that is relevant for what I want to do - Auditors Report for 2012:/ ). Keep in mind that the database I am working with has an easy 50 tables in it with at least 6 or 7 years worth of data in it.

Possible Solution/s:
1. Copy database into new database, delete everything except 2012 data.
2. Copy both tables and throw them into a new database, delete all rows except 2012 data.

The I.T. guy before me created a database for 2011 and was able to create the auditors report. I however, have never done this type of task before. Any help would greatly be appreciated and I will be watching this question til 4pm EST time. Hopefully I was specific in my request, but if not, I will be right here waiting to reply to you:). THANKS!

Comment: Would a view that limits the data to only 2012 not work?  Do you have to move it to a different server rather than query using a view on the server which it currently sits?

Comment: what is the size of the database ? (in Mo/Go of mdf, ndf and ldf)

Comment: Well I have a query that puts together the auditors report. But I cannot run it on the current database because it has 2013 data in it. The I.T. guy before me told me that the way to go about this is to create a new database and to throw the data for the year you want in it(e.g. throw 2012 data in 2012 database)

Comment: So you're unable to change the query?

Comment: the size of the database is over 3 GB

Comment: It would be harder to change the query to fit my needs than yo just copy the tables I need into another database and have only 2012 data in that new database. The current query to get the auditors report is 8 Select SUM(ColumnName) statements nested under 1 SELECT statement.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely knowledgeable on the utilities available for SQL Server, but based on utilities otherwise available,

1. Find a dump utility to export the data on the tables.
   Often such export utilities will allow specifying the table names,
   and often will take where conditions.
   The export will be in SQL, and can be used to populate a new database.
2. Create the new database on the same server as the source database.
   Do a cross-database update.
   So, create a database db2012.
   Using database db2012, run the following update statement:

.

```
update table1
(select * from d1.table1 where year(timestamp_x) = 2012)
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest thing is:

```
select t.*
into newdb..t
from olddb..t
where <from the last two years>
```

For each of the tables.  This will get the data.

If you need other things (indexes, contraints, etc.), then script out the table definitions, recreate them in the new database, and insert the data from the existing tables.

Comment: Yes.  "t" would be for one table.  You would have to run it twice for two tables.

Comment: and "where <from the last two years>"? Will it really retrieve the last two years from that WHERE clause? Ive never seen that before.

Comment: @user2001006 . . . Not at all.  You have to put in the `where` condition to make this happen.  You didn't give the format of the tables in your question, so there is no way for an outsider to divine what the condition really is.

Comment: lol sorry bout that. I was confused. Thanks to anyone who responded to my question!!! This is not an easy thing to tackle by yourself.